# set a custom download folder android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hello  guys I'm working on app that download some files I would like to allow the user to choose a custom download directory,they can create a folder for example in which the files would be stored how can I get around it ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use Storage Access Framework for letting users to choose directory with Intent and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. onActivityResult get Uri and save it as a String with SharedPreferences and save to this folder with DocumentFile class.

Comment: thank you but can u please add some more details I'm a beginner thanks again